# extract figures from a html table out of yahoo finance | Excel VBA webscraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, yahoo-finance

Hi I need help with this code I'm trying to extract data from this page, "Earnings History" block:
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/analysis?p=MSFT

Been sitting & frustrating on this for already 4 hours. Any help/hint is highly appreciated!

Regards Milan

```
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim aEle As HTMLDocument
Dim y As Long
Dim x As String
Dim lastrow As Long

Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

objIE.Visible = True

lastrow = Sheets("Table5").usedrange.Row - 1 + Sheets("Table5").usedrange.Rows.Count


For y = 11 To lastrow Step 2

x = Sheets("Table5").Range("A" & y).Value
If x = "" Then
Exit Sub
Else
objIE.navigate "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & x & "/analysis?p=" & x

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        For Each aEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("BdT Bdc($seperatorColor)")
    
        'On Error Resume Next
        If InStr(aEle.innerText, "EPS Actual") > 0 Then
        Sheets("Table5").Range("T" & y).Value = aEle.Children(4).innerText
        Sheets("Table5").Range("U" & y).Value = aEle.Children(3).innerText
        Sheets("Table5").Range("V" & y).Value = aEle.Children(2).innerText
        Sheets("Table5").Range("W" & y).Value = aEle.Children(1).innerText

        Exit For
        End If
        Next
       
    
End If
Next y
End Sub
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to parse from `Earnings History` table?

Comment: Thanks for your message! Basically the figures from the row 'EPS Actual'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the content across the row `EPS Actua` out of the table `Earnings History` from that site using xmlhttp requests. You don't need to go for IE. Give it a shot.

```
Sub FetchValue()
    Const Url$ = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/analysis?p=MSFT&guccounter=1"
    Dim elem As Object, tRow As Object, S$, R&

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36"
        .Send
        S = .responseText
    End With
    
    With CreateObject("HTMLFile")
        .write S
        For Each elem In .getElementsByTagName("tr")
            If InStr(elem.innerText, "EPS Actual") > 0 Then
                R = R + 1: Cells(R, 1) = elem.Children(1).innerText
                Cells(R, 2) = elem.Children(2).innerText
                Cells(R, 3) = elem.Children(3).innerText
                Cells(R, 4) = elem.Children(4).innerText
                Exit For
            End If
        Next elem
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly, will embed it in my code. Parsing with 'xmlhttp requests' seems much faster than my IE approach. under which conditions is this applicable, can any website be extracted via this approach? Best to you and regards, Milan

Comment: You can scrape any site using xmlhttp requests only when the content you are interested in are not javascript heavy. The easiest way to figure out whether any content is dynamic is to look the the same in page source. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sim! Do you have a clue why this approach shows an error for the table on this website: [link](https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=amzn)

I need the values from the last row of the table (starting with 'Recom'), but i get this error on my children(x) rows: Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: `
With CreateObject("HTMLFile")
        .write S
        
        For Each elem In .getElementsByTagName("tr")
        
        If InStr(elem.innerText, "Recom") > 0 Then

        Sheets("Tabelle5").Range("AD" & y) = elem.Children(1).innerText
        Sheets("Tabelle5").Range("AE" & y) = elem.Children(3).innerText
        
        End If
        Next elem
    End With
`

Comment: Hi Milan, consider creating a new post describing your current requirement as the site you are trying with is different from the one in your question here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion I like using VBA Seleniumbasic Chromedriver from get hub. I find it easier to work with. Then you can use the Chrome extension RUTO XPath Finder, to find the XPaths of the elements and table references on the page. Then just reference the xpath. both can be installed without admin privileges.